# Find specific text in column and insert row with column headers

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to macros. I have combined three tables together into one. All need to have different headings based on the value in first column.

[image]

I am trying to do the following:

[image]

Hopefully somebody can help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    If Cells(1, 1) = "Veg" Then
        Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Cells(1, 1) = "Col1"
        Cells(1, 2) = "Col2"
        Cells(1, 3) = "Col3"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Vityata, but I am trying to do something like that convert the data in table 1 to table 2. Image